# FM Mobile: Destroy Form

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

How i can destroy form, I want: creatr Form1(start application), create Form 2, destroy Form1,  working with form2, then create form 3, destroy form2. but I not know how to destroy form.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/q/27818697/960757.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FM Mobile Destroy Form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26006752/fm-mobile-destroy-form)

Answer (score 3):

Call `DisposeOf()` on each Form when needed.