# FM Mobile Destroy Form

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey, delphi-xe5, delphi-xe6

How i can destroy form, I want: creatr Form1(start application), create Form 2, destroy Form1, working with form2, then create form 3, destroy form2. but I not know how to destroy form.
If i call:

```
procedure TFPressStartScreen.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MainScreen.FMainScreen := MainScreen.TFMainScreen.Create(Application);
  MainScreen.FMainScreen.Show;
  DisposeOf;
end;
```

FPressStartScreen - 1 form, FMainScreen - 2 form, i create 2 form and need destroy 1. but i get access violation.

Comment: What does the AccessViolation actually say?  What line does the debugger say the AV is coming from?

Comment: DisposeOf; when i desrtoy second form

Comment: That is not what I asked.  What is the actual error message of the AV? And the code you showed is calling `DisposeOf()` on the first form, not the second form.  Please provide a [SCCCE](http://sscce.org) demonstrating the issue.

Comment: Project Project1.apk raised exception class Segmentation fault (11).

Comment: Destroying the first created form in the project file is like cutting the tree you are sitting on. You must not do that. It is a special form `Application.MainForm` and the base for the application.